# registry sub keys don't match whats in registry

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, registry

Using the following code:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");
```

I get a list of keys from the registry.  This list however doesn't match whats in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` in the actual registry. The list I get from the code looks like its from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` instead.  Is there a permissions issue here?

Comment: Are you running this as 32-bit or 64-bit? There's various differences in the Registry depending on which - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305097

Comment: Compare it to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node, you'll probably see a better match.  If you run 32-bit on a 64-bit operating system then you'll have to understand how the [Registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works.

Comment: it is 64 bit, thanks, ill have a look

Comment: I forgot the development version of the app is 32 bit but the production version is 64 bit.  So the Wow6432Node was missing my entry.  I added it in and it found it, magic!